# Customize Tumblr bookmarklet to only post to a certain account

Tags: tumblr, bookmarklet

I frequently post to tumblr via the tumblr bookmarklet. I also manage two different tumblr sites and once in awhile I would accidentally post content meant for one site onto the other (forgot that I was logged in with the wrong account).

Does anyone know a way to customize the bookmarklet so that it will only post to a specific account? Or at least warn that the wrong account is currently active?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about bookmarklets are no longer on-topic on Web Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Tumblr bookmarklet, but I use the Posterous bookmarklet to post to multiple accounts, or selected accounts. Heard rumors that posting to Tumblr from Posterous sometimes doesn't work too well, but I do not have such problem for the past 1 year.